# Connect HP Printer to Computer while computer works over wifi internet

Tags: printer, laser-printer

I am using my system over wifi internet and i want to connect my HP Printer Laser Jet CP 2025 with my system how can i do this?

Comment: That printer does not seem to offer Air Print, so probably you cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

As @John pointed out in a comment, your printer does not support WiFi, so you cannot connect it that way. However, I can see two other possibilities.

1. The CP2025 has a USB interface, so you can connect it that way. If other PCs also need access, that can be done over WiFi by sharing the printer on the PC it is connected to.
2. The printer also has a LAN port. If your WiFi router has any LAN ports (RJ45 sockets) then you can plug the printer into that and connect that way.

If you decide that either of these is possible, I can add more details if you let me know which method you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the printer does not have WiFi builtin, you need something to bridge through. The easiest solution is to use an Ethernet-2-WiFi adapter. These things are cheap and work with pretty much any network device.

In Canada you can [get one for about $75 CDN](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B018YPWORE/?coliid=I3IKJ7OOWVDWY9&colid=29Z3AQHI5VPTA&psc=1&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it) which is which is about $60 USD. There are plenty of others but I had good luck IOGear.

Now, the work of this device can be done by any device with a network port and WiFi, including a computer to use as print-server if you have one available. What you need is to install and configure software to expose the printer for network sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I have a non-wifi HP printer and it is painful to run a cable all over the house to get it to work. With the [BrosTrend AC1200 ethernet to wifi adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0118SPFCK), my printer is now on my wifi network and prints nicely. It is a life-saver!